# Z-index on a element with fixed position

Tags: css, html, position, z-index

I have a left panel with fixed position(it's always on the left side, nomatter how much you scroll) and also few elements in that left panel. On a certain event a mask appears(it goes over everything because `position:fixed; z-index: 102`).

My goal is when X event fires and the mask come up, to show up the `holder` element over the mask.

**Here is a fiddle showing my problem:** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DJA5F/3/)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="leftpanel">
    <div class="just-random-elem" style="height: 30px;">just an element to move the holder abit down</div>
    <div class="holder">asdasdas</div>
</div>
<div class="mask"></div>

<div style="height: 9999px;">Just to make sure both mask and leftpanel are with fixed positions.</div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
.mask {
    opacity: 0.85;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: #000;
}
.leftpanel {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 15px;
}
.holder {
    width: 230px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 99999;  <<<<<<<<<< This is NOT working!
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index

Comment: What are you trying to show me with this link?

Comment: \*sigh* `Applies to: […]`

Comment: Well, I've checked this documentation, still don't know what is the actual problem.

Comment: “Applies to: positioned elements” – _is_ your `.holder` element positioned? No, it is _not_ – so `z-index` simply has no effect on it, no matter how ridiculously high a value you use. Just add `position:relative` – problem solved … D’oh!

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, before I asked this question. Couldn't get it working. (I tried adding `position:relative` to .holder class)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DJA5F/4/ … works that way in every browser I tested – except Chrome. Not sure if Chrome is handling stacking contexts correct here and the others are not – or if it’s the other way around. Works in Chrome if you put `#mask` into `.leftpanel`: http://jsfiddle.net/DJA5F/5/ – might not be the nicest workaround, but since it’s postioned fixed, it does not actually matter, since the orientation for fixed is the viewport. (And here is the version without _ridiculous_ z-index values: http://jsfiddle.net/DJA5F/6/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's great! I'm using such z-index value, because the app is complex with alot of dinamyc elements, drag and drops and so on, but yeah the values are too high. Please add this as answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Yeah OK, that might make “higher” z-index values necessary – but one should try to keep them reasonable, f.e. go up to a 100 or maybe 1000. Otherwise, if you go for 99999 here straight away, that might be problematic should you come across a case where you would need to display another element on top of that still … And IIRC older IE had a bug, where the max. z-index value they would accept was 32768 (2^15) …

Comment: Okey, Thanks again. Gonna fix the values now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.holder` element is no positioned, so z-index simply has no effect on it. You need to add a position value different from the default `static` – `relative` will do.

http://jsfiddle.net/DJA5F/4 works that way in every browser I tested – except Chrome. Can’t spontaneously say if Chrome is handling stacking contexts correct here and the others are not – or if it’s the other way around.
Works in Chrome as well if you put `#mask` into `.leftpanel`: http://jsfiddle.net/DJA5F/5 – might not be the nicest workaround, but since it’s postioned fixed, it does not actually matter, since the orientation for fixed is the viewport.